# Como pegar o último id gerado no php usando angular?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Seguinte, estou cadastrando cep e preciso pegar o id desse cep, recém, cadastrado para inserir na tabela de usuários.
Tentei fazer em pdo usando o mesmo arquivo php que cadastrei o cep... Deu pau, pois apareceu mensagem no console dizendo que não reconhecia as variáveis do cep.
Estou pensando em fazer o cadastro de usuários, separado do de ceps, mas como eu "levo" o id do cep para o outro arquivo php?

angular:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []) 
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope) {

})

.controller('enderecoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.adicionarEndereco = function (endereco) {
        $http.post("php/salvaEndereco.php", endereco).success(function (data){

        });
        $location.path('/cadastraUsuario');
    }
})

.controller('usuarioCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.pegaUsuario = function (usuario) {
    $http.post("php/salvaEndereco.php", usuario).success(function (data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
})
```

php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X-Requested-With');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$cep  = $data->cep;
$uf  = $data->uf;
$cidade  = $data->cidade;
$bairro  = $data->bairro;
$logradouro  = $data->logradouro;

$insereEndereco=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO cep (idCep, cep, uf, cidade, bairro, logradouro) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereEndereco->bindValue(1, NULL); 
$insereEndereco->bindValue(2, $cep); 
$insereEndereco->bindValue(3, $uf); 
$insereEndereco->bindValue(4, $cidade);
$insereEndereco->bindValue(5, $bairro);
$insereEndereco->bindValue(6, $logradouro);

$insereEndereco->execute();
$idCep = $pdo->lastInsertId();
?>
```

Comment: Qual banco usa?

Comment: Por que fazer isso no Angular? Se você precisa apenas do último, faça um select no php para retornar apenas o último, ao invés de retornar toda a lista e depois fazer o filtro com js. Mais prático. A não ser que os demais dados sejam usados para outro fim.

Comment: Estou usando mysql

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, obrigado pela dica, mas já estou fazendo de uma outra forma...
retorno só o id do cep, no final do cadastro, depois pego ele no controler, salvo ele no localStorage e no controler do usuário, pego ele de volta do localStorage e insiro ele junto com o objeto usuário... Entendeu? hehehehe

Comment: 0_0 acho que retornar pelo php é mais prático, pois o php tem a função de pegar o último valor cadastrado. Você não precisa dar tanta volta, fica menos propício a erros e a aplicação fica mais leve. =D Da uma procurada por isso ai ;)

Comment: Mas e como você vai fazer o select no banco pra pegar o último id, quando houver vários ceps cadastrados?

Comment: PHP não é minha área, mas em um projeto recente, o pessoal do backend fez um retorno desse, onde ele pega o último valor cadastrado no banco e retorna. Só tem que tomar cuidado para não correr o risco de haver insert simultaneo. Bem improvável de haver, mas é sempre bom verificar.

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo, se o teu Banco trouxer sempre um id unico pra cada cep, basta vc fazer o SELECT que busca o último id cadastrado, ordenando por id, mesmo, DESC. Dessa forma vc busca o mais recente. Depois, na inserção, coloca uma regrinha de +1 e voilà! : )